# How to get error message on a HTML5 Application Cache Error event?

Tags: html, html5-appcache

During the caching of my offline webapp I receive a totally valid error which is displayed in the browser console like this:

```
Application Cache Error event: Manifest changed during update, scheduling retry
```

I can add a Listener to be informed that an error has occured.

```
window.applicationCache.addEventListener('error', function(e){
  //handle error here
}, false);
```

How can I get the error detail, in this case "**Manifest changed during update, scheduling retry**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use window.onerror. The callback can have three parameters:

```
Error message (string)
Url where error was raised (string)
Line number where error was raised (number)
```

check this for more information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onerror

Answer (score 1):

Still a valid issue today. In my example, my error log does not return anything. I am using IE11.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" manifest="icozum.appcache">
```

onChecking events fires but then onError with cache status = 0 which is nocached.

```
 window.applicationCache.onchecking = function (e) {
       var doc = document.getElementById("cachestatus");
       if (doc != null) {
            doc.innerHTML += "Checking the cache.\n";
       }
 }
```

Then onError

```
window.applicationCache.onerror = function (e) {
    var doc = document.getElementById("cachestatus");
    if (doc != null) {
         doc.innerHTML += "Cache error occurred." + applicationCache.status.toString() + "\n";
         console.log(e);
         console.log("test");
     }
 }
```

The output on the screen is

> Checking the cache.
>   Cache error occurred.0

There is no detail info about the error in onError event handler. I got the real error by pressing the F12. Here is the screen shot. Is there any way to capture this much detail in onError event handler.

[image]

And finally I figured out the problem. The error is not due to missing file. The app cache file does exist, however in windows , visual studio (2013)/IIS does not recognize the extension `.appcache`. The following section needs to be added to the `web.config` file.

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".appcache" mimeType="text/cache-manifest"/>
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```